# I want to launch an activity and a widget at the same time

Tags: android, widget

my widget is working fine and i don't need to open the activity by tapping the widget. But, I need to launch the activity as a launcher and also want to open it manually whenever i want. The problem is that the activity is launching under the OnReceive method of appwidgetprovider but there are no icon found in for that launcher activity. 
When i close it at the first time it launched, i can't find any icon to open it again(the activity).

Here is my code.. of `appwidgetprovider` class

```
public class CurrentMoodWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static final String WIDGETTAG = "WidgetMood";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Picture.class);
    // FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is needed because we're not in an activity
    // already, without it we crash.
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    Log.i(WIDGETTAG, "onUpdate");
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Log.i(WIDGETTAG, "updating widget[id] " + appWidgetId);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout); 

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CurrentMoodService.class);
        intent.setAction(CurrentMoodService.UPDATEMOOD);

        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetBtn, pendingIntent);
        Log.i(WIDGETTAG, "pending intent set");

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
   }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define at same time activity & receiver in manifest.
eg.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="Your Package Name"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action 
                android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: I have done just the same in my manifest but still there is no icon of my launcher activity.. Just like before it is launching but after closing that there is no icon found

Comment: I want to clear that there is also a service which is called "CurrentMoodService" and it is called perfectly by the onUpdate method and i also have added it to manifest as..
<service android:name=".CurrentMoodService"> </service>